# Blank page after onepage login

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, login

When I login to my account both during checkout process or through the regular login page I get a white page. After refreshing that page I get redirected to my dashboard, but not before.

My .htaccess file has php_value memory_limit 128M and my index.php has ini_set('display_errors', 1); uncommented. Also my apache logs are not showing any errors.

The form is trying to reach http://www.mywebsite.com/customer/account/loginPost/ and that's where it's stuck in a blank page.

EDIT: On the backend **Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in** was checked to No, changed it to Yes but same thing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A white page is (usually) a PHP startup error. You need to just check all your corresponding logs, Magento logs, PHP logs etc.

If you're using `mod_php` then Apache will log the errors, if not, then you'll need to define the `cgi` wrapper or PHP itself to log errors; as Apache won't be aware of them.

Follow [this guide](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) - there is a section specifically about enabling PHP error display and logging.

Comment: as I said I have no errors on my logs but I meant no errors about this issue. The logs are working as I get stuff like: [Wed May 22 15:44:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Users/Maggie/Sites/jardiloisir/skin/frontend/jardiloisirs/default/images/line.jpg, referer: http://jardiloisir.local/skin/frontend/jardiloisirs/default/css/styles.css But nothing related to this issue

Comment: Follow that [guide](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) - if you don't have an error, its either because you aren't looking at the right log, or you haven't enabled logging.

Comment: the error logs weren't helping but renaming app/local did, now I have yet to find the issue at hand but I know where to look exactly